# Rails if statement using include? method giving either syntax or string literal error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my RoR app, I am trying to create a method that will look at a text field (body) and post a message to slack if a UK mobile phone number has been shared. I am testing for the UK mobile phone number by searching for `07` or '+447' appearing anywhere in the body text.

```
  def contact_details_shared
    if self.body.include? '07' || self.body.include? '+447'
      slack_post(self)
    end
  end
```

This gives the following error when I try to launch the app in localhost (e.g. rails s):

`syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'`

But I can't see any syntax issues here.

So I also tried the following

```
  def contact_details_shared
    if ( self.body.include? '07' || self.body.include? '+447' )
      slack_post(self)
    end
  end
```

This gives the following error when I try to launch the app in localhost (e.g. rails s):

`warning: string literal in condition`

I was surprised by this because my code should be returning a boolean for each OR condition (not a string).

So... two questions:
1) How can I get the code to work?
2) I imagine there are solutions that are altogether more elegant than mine. Suggestions very welcome! Any ideas?

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried `if self.body.include?('07') || self.body.include?('+447')`?

Comment: Nice! Seems to work now.

Comment: Some times you have to uses brackets, ruby interpreter has some priorities to process operators and your original code is ambiguous. Brakets eliminates that ambiguity.

Comment: @arieljuod - Perhaps you mean parentheses? I believe brackets (`[]`) would throw an error, yes?

Comment: yes, sorry, I meant parentheses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
if self.body.include?('07') || self.body.include?('+447')
```

I suspect ruby needs the explicit identification of the arguments (i.e., `'07'` and `'+447'`) provided by the use of parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```
    See this magic:

    Ex: "hello07".include? '07'

    return true

    when you use

    "hello07".include? '+441'

    returns false

    "hello07".include? '07' || "hello07".include? '+441'

    SyntaxError: (irb):39: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting end-of-input
    "hello07".include? '07' || "hello07".include? "+441"

                                                ^
    if you use "or" instead of ||

     "hello07".include?'07' or "hello07".include?'+447'
    returns true


    if you want to work your code, you can use

    if self.body.include?('07') or self.body.include?('+447')


    the solution is use "or" instead of "||"

if you want use the "||" use this syntax
if (self.body.include?'07') || (self.body.include?'+447')
```